# If statement not working using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable that gets the text from a div. I compare that text using an `if` statement and then apply CSS to it depending on if it is true or false. For some reason, I cannot get it to work. The variable is getting the correct text because I verified through `console.log` but the `if` statement is not working. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var singleStatus = $('.single-status').text();
    console.log(singleStatus); // This outputs 'Pending' to the console
    if(singleStatus === 'Pending'){
        $('.single-status').css('color', '#f2721d'); // This does nothing
        console.log(singleStatus); // This does nothing...
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: Can you reproduce this error, in the stack snippets here, or elsewhere with [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? That looks functional.

Comment: `$.trim()` the string to remove any unwanted whitespace around the text.

Comment: try to do a less specific compare and see if that works `==` instead of `===`

Comment: @somethinghere: If `text()` returned anything other than a string, I would be *really* worried :)

Comment: Does it work with == as opposed to ===?

Comment: @dwhite.me: Again: If `text()` returned anything other than a string, I would be really *really* worried :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my original comment as answer...

**Assume whitespace in text content:**

The most common problem with console logging, is that you can't see a lot of whitespace. Whitespace is traditionally the characters that provide formatting but are invisible. These include `Space`, `Tab`, `Carriage return` & `Line feed`.

Your div most likely has a carriage return, or spaces, or tabs, in it around `Pending` (usually as a result of prettifying the HTML in most editors):

e.g. it may actually look like:

```
<div>Pending
</div>
```

or

```
<div>Pending </div>
```

or even

```
<div>
   Pending
</div>
```

and `text()` returns all text content *including whitespace*.

**Solution:**

Use `$.trim` to remove unwanted whitespace before the comparison:

```
if($.trim(singleStatus) === 'Pending'){
```

You don't want to use `string.trim()` as not all browsers support it. That's why jQuery provides the static `$.trim()` method.

**Note:** As `text()` returns a string (or undefined) changing the comparison to `==` will have no effect on the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I'm at lunch and will test it once I get back. I am thinking your answer may be the correct one. I already tried == and it rendered the same results.

Comment: I thought it would make no difference, but i just tested my own theory on the `==`.  great note, i actually had just assumed the opposite.

Comment: @Jonathon Hibbard: Since when is `==` case-insensitive? :) http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fgea3onb/

Comment: I'm an idiot for saying that and have noted that already lol.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie indeed the equals wouldn't make a difference. Long day :) good answer! Very curious whether it solved it...

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie That was the answer! Thank you for figuring that out for me.

Comment: @DC TC: No problem. Specifically what was it? Space? CR? Tab?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie it was whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of problems here.

You'll probably need to do something like casting the value to lowercase (`singleStatus.toLowerCase()`), trimming all whitespace off ( using a regex replace or something similar ) along with ensuring anything else (like html, or whatever else) that could possibly cause the strings not to equate.  You'll need to do all this preparation and sanitization *before* evaluating it and checking for the value you're after.

if there is any differences whatsoever between strings, it will fail.

**>>>Edit<<<**

To be clear here, the use of `toLowerCase()` and trim and anything else like that - the whole point is to get the strings as generic as possible.  you'd then have to just evaluate it as `str === 'pending'`.  this will ensure that the string case is the same, and also require less work to ensure that there are capital letters wherever it is you may be looking for them.

**>>> Edit 2<<<**

Updated my answer by removing references to `==` and `===`

Answer (score -1):

may be your solution is:

```js
$('#btn').click(function(e){  
    var singleStatus = $('.single-status').text();
    alert(singleStatus);    
    if(singleStatus === 'Pending'){
        $('.single-status').css('color', '#f2721d'); // This does nothing
        console.log(singleStatus); // This does nothing...
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single-status">Pending</div><button id="btn"> click</button>
```

Comment: Aside from changing `log` to `alert`, and providing your own HTML *which may not match*, how does this solve the problem? :)

Comment: i said may be ...buddy

Comment: *Maybe* indeed. How could this suggestion *possibly* solve the problem? You have not actually changed anything related to the cause :)